# Sum & Update Array values jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I'm currently doing a profiling quiz, I've decided to use jQuery and php.

The issue is that each answer has different values.

For example for question n°1 :

```
When you look in the mirror :

    a - You smile = profile handsom -> 3
                  = profile cute -> 2

    b - You run   = profile shy -> 3
                  = profile uglly -> 1

    c - Who's that = profile yolo -> 2
                   = profile zen -> 3
```

And so on. The result of the game gives you the profile with more points.

Here's my idea. I create an array of values [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], each one is a profile.

Each answer of the game is an array, for the example above :

```
a => [3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b => [0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0]
c => [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3]
```

**My question is**: how I update this same array summing the values?

My array, in the end, must like :

```
array(32, 17, 0, 5, 10, 2)
```

Then I'll sort it and obtain my profile.

I think this can be done only with jQuery but I can use some php. Thank you very much, the problem is tricky so I hope I've explain it properly :)

Comment: Where is the PHP and jQuery code???

Comment: How is this `array(32, 17, 0, 5, 10, 2)` coming?

Comment: I haven't done any code yet, it's just what a thought of, I din't know how to write it here. Sorry.

Comment: As @void is asking, how did you come up with `array(32, 17, 0, 5, 10, 2)`? Also, if you run there's a low chance that you'd be ugly? I better start running.

Comment: I don't understand very well. How the final array is formed?

Comment: Personally I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you're trying to do here, and I think that may stem from the fact that you're not entirely clear on what you're trying to accomplish either. In any case, StackOverfkiw isn't a code-writing service; you may want to Google some coding tutorials before going much further with this project